# cylindrical pcb design and casing

Tags: pcb-design, connector, pcb-assembly, cable-assemblies, cases

I'm trying to desing a control system that measures some analog signals like differantial pressure, temperature, motor current etc... and then produces some control signals and sends information to PC. My system includes three cylindrical pcb card. They needs to be placed in a cylindrical case.

[image]

The problem is there are too much signal but there is limited PCB area. 
I tought to use stack connectors to transmit power and signals but the stack connectors take too much place so that there won't be enough place for other components like DSP Chip, Ethernet PHY.

[image]

Could there be a better solution to transmit the signals except stack connectors?
Could you recommend a layout structure to get a more efficient placement?

Comment: OK so the PCBs themselves are not cylindrical, just the enclosure they fit in? Dimensions would help. Circuit complexity would help. Photographs would help. Mounting components on both sides of PCBs might help.

Comment: PCP's are cylindrical too. Radius is 3cm. It's not possible to send photos because I'm at the design phase.

Comment: Do you mean PCBs are round? To be cylindrical they have to be made from flexible material and bent to shape.

Comment: Yes I mean round, circular

Comment: how do you solder flat components to round pcbs? Anyway, if I understand your question correctly you can route your signals through the case, you connect all your circular pcbs to another pcb that is attached to the case, so the connectors are only on top (and/or bottom) and you get plenty of room for components.

Comment: What is the diameter of your PCBs, and how many signals do you need to pass from board to board? They make some very compact board-to-board connectors these days, and I have seen many examples of this being done successfully.

Comment: I still have no idea what these boards look like

Comment: What board-to-board connectors are you using? There are countless models of fine-pitch ones meant to be used for stuff like this.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The view is of a cross-section of a *horizontal* tube with round PCBs sitting vertically. Threw me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely explore dumping the stacked connectors in favor of **independent** SMT connectors on each side.

You can get very fine-pitch (sub-mm pitch) connectors that will use up less total area, and you can optimize placement and pin count to find the space you need. You might have to use a higher technology multilayer board, but that is a small price for such a compact product.

If your budget will support it, a rigid- flex arrangement with flex running between the outside edges of flatted round rigid boards would be close to ideal. It could be built and tested flat as a unit then depanelized and assembled.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind hand assembly and difficult repairs, one trick is to use [castellated holes](http://www.hitech.com.mk/en/technology/castell) around the perimeter of your PCBs, and then solder lengths of bare wire into them to build up your stack.

Obviously, the inner surface of the case must be non-conductive for this to work. Either make the case out of plastic, or if you use metal, line it with Kapton tape or use heat-shrink tubing on the completed assembly.